# AWS Lambda function not able to find other packages in same directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dockerfile, amazon-ecr

I am deploying a lambda function as a container image.
Here's my project structure :

- core
- plugins
- lambda_handler.py

All three are at the same level - `/var/task`

Inside lambda_handler.py I am importing the core package, but when I test it locally it says :

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_handler': No module named 'core'"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

# Copy requirements to container
COPY requirements.txt .

# install dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Copy app folders to container
COPY core ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY plugins ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY lambda_handler.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY __init__.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD ["lambda_handler.lambda_fun"]
```

lambda_handler.py

```
import json

from core.nlp.service import nlp_service


def lambda_fun(event, context):
    return json.dumps(nlp_service.get_ner())
```

requirements.txt

```
pyspark==3.1.2
spacy
pymupdf
boto3
cloudpathlib
spark-nlp==3.4.1
numpy
```

Comment: What is your docker file and full code for `lambda_handler.py`?

Comment: What is `requirements.txt`?

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just use

```
COPY core ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
```

it will copy the content of the `core` into `${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}`. To copy into `core` folder, it should be:

```
COPY core ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/core
```